# How to get my question answered by sharing the link across stack exchange sites

Tags: discussion, questions, stackexchange, related-problems, share

I posted a [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/67348/21184) (related to wordpress) at **wordpress.stackexchange**.

**How can I share the question** across a similar site **"Superuser"** (it has a tag for wordpress)?

**Is it possible or not?**

I want this feature to increase the viewers to my question so that I can get answers fast and correct.

Comment: To begin with: If you want to increase views on your question, you'll have to [write an interesting enough question](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-answers/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice, as to which SE site to post your question to, is an important one, as cross-posting is [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/189958).

The mechanism that comes closest to your question is *migration*, but that is likely not what you are looking for.

You could also advertise your post via Facebook, Twitter, or Google+ via the *share* link below your question.

Adding a bounty is another good way to increase traffic to your question.

As for your question in particular, it would seem to me that you're on track to get some great help.  You've got a diamond actively helping to get the best solution.

Comment: Now I understood correctly about SE site! Thanks @Josh

Comment: A lengthy discussion on the subject can be found here: http://meta.superuser.com/q/2807/128794